# Replace the multiple values between 2 characters in azure sql

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

In Azure SQL, I'm attempting to delete any text that is present between the `<` and `>` characters to my column in my table

Sample text:

> The best part is that. < br >Note:< br >< u> reading
> :< /u> < span style="font-family: calibri,sans-serif; font-size: 11pt;"> moral stories from an early age
> < b>not only helps your child.< /b>< br>< u>in
> learning important: < /u>< /span>< span style="font-family: calibri;
> ">life lessons but it also helps, in language development.< /span>< ./span>

Output:

> The best part is that. reading: moral stories from an early age not only helps your child in learning important: life lessons but it also helps in language development.

I tried below query its working only for small comments text:

```
SELECT [Comments],REPLACE([Comments], SUBSTRING([Comments], CHARINDEX('<', [Comments]), CHARINDEX('>', [Comments]) - CHARINDEX('<', [Comments]) + 1),'') AS result
FROM table
```

Comment: Are you working with Azure Synapse Analytics?  Rather than Azure SQL Data Warehouse which is its predecessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I have taken input table named **check_1** and sample data is inserted into that table.

[image]

- This query removes only the first occurring pattern.

```
SELECT [Comments],REPLACE([Comments], SUBSTRING([Comments], CHARINDEX('<', [Comments]), CHARINDEX('>', [Comments]) - CHARINDEX('<', [Comments]) + 1),'') AS result
FROM check_1
```

- In order to remove all string patterns beginning with '<' and ending with '>' in the text, a user defined function with a while loop is created.

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_removetags] (@input_text VARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS  VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @pos_1 INT
DECLARE @pos_n INT
DECLARE @Length INT
SET @pos_1 =  CHARINDEX('<',@input_text)
SET @pos_n =  CHARINDEX('>',@input_text,CHARINDEX('<',@input_text))
SET @Length = (@pos_n - @pos_1) +  1

WHILE @pos_1 >  0  AND @pos_n >  0  AND @Length >  0
BEGIN
SET @input_text =  replace(@input_text,substring(@input_text,@pos_1,@Length),'')
SET @pos_1 =  CHARINDEX('<',@input_text)
SET @pos_n =  CHARINDEX('>',@input_text,CHARINDEX('<',@input_text))
SET @Length = (@pos_n - @pos_1) +  1
END

RETURN  @input_text
END
```

```
select [dbo].[udf_removetags](comments) as result from check_1
```

[image]

Output String:
The best part is that. Note: reading :  moral stories from an early age not only helps your child.in learning important: life lessons but it also helps, in language development.

You can also use Stuff [Refer Microsoft document on [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)] in place of replace+substring function.
Replace this `SET @input_text =  replace(@input_text,substring(@input_text,@pos_1,@Length),'')`
line with the line
`SET @input_text =  STUFF(@input_text,@pos_1,@Length,'')`
in the user defined function.

Result will be same.

Answer (score 0):

According to [https://learn.microsoft.com/../azure/../regexp_replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/functions/regexp_replace) Azure supports `REGEXP_REPLACE`.

This means it should be possible to replace all `'<...>'` by `''` via

```
select regexp_replace(comments, '<[^>]*>', '') from mytable;
```